# fetch friends of users from facebook faster

Tags: php, facebook

i am trying to get data of friends of users of facebook . I was using two seperate query one to get name , and id and other one to get the gender .but it makes the data loading so slow .is there is a possible way to use one query to get the name, id , pic , and gander for all facebook friends of the user .

here are the two queries i made within different functions

```
 function getFacebookFriends($criteria='') {
  $name = $criteria['name'];

  if($name=='') $name = 'me';

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$name.'/friends?access_token='.$this->getAccessToken();
$content = $this->getDataFromUrl($url);
$content = json_decode($content,true);

$users = $this->formatFacebookUsers($content);

return $users;
}
```

and this is the other one in different function

```
        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user_id.'?fields=gender';
        //echo '<a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">'.$url.'</a><br>';
        $data = json_decode($this->getDataFromUrl($url));

        $fb['gender'] = $data->gender;
```

i am using this one to get gender

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user_id.'?fields=gender';
```

can there be just one request send for getting all the needs i want?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cgender

Comment: @CBroe thank you for linking me to facebook developers but i tried using it and i really getting slow loading speed if there is more then 100 friends of any users. i tested it with a account with 500 friends and it took 5 minutes to display me the result

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if there's an alternative method, but considering you're using PHP, you might want to look into using multi_curl, you get incredible speeds (orders of magnitudes higher) as the operating system dispatches all outbound requests in parallel

http://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/

Comment: That looks promising let me check this out first